# RESTORE HEADERONLY FROM DISK ServerName column

Tags: sql-server, database-backups

I've a LocalDB instance `(localdb)\foo` (version 12.0.6024.0) and a database called `myDB`.

I backup the database and perform this query: `RESTORE HEADERONLY FROM DISK = 'C:\\myDB.bak';`

In ServerName column is not `(localdb)\foo` as expected.

[image: different ServerName]

How to get the original ServerName from the BAK file?
Or to decode the displayed one?

Comment: `(localdb)\foo` is not the name of the server, that's just the special connection string for LocalDB. Use `SELECT @@SERVERNAME` to see what it is

Comment: You're right, `SELECT @@SERVERNAME` gives me the same value as `RESTORE HEADERONLY FROM DISK = 'C:\\myDB.bak';` Still is there any way how to get the value `(localdb)\foo`?

Comment: Not in T-SQL I don't think, it doesn't exist. It's just a way for the client to connect to LocalDB.